# pgfplots: Order of Options Influences `xlabel style` (Line Break)

Tags: pgfplots

I want to have a **line break** in the **`xlabel`** and **`ylabel`**. Somehow the **position** of the **option** `xlabel style` and `ylabel style` has an **effect on** the **outcome**, is that expected behavior?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ylabel style = {align = left},
        xlabel style = {align = right},
        xlabel = {aaa\\ bbb},   
        ylabel = {aaa\\ bbb},   
        axis lines = center,
        xmin = -80,
        xmax = 60,
        ymin = -15,
        ymax = 15,
        enlarge x limits = 0.05,
        enlarge y limits = 0.05,
%       ylabel style = {align = left},
%       xlabel style = {align = right},
%       xlabel = {aaa\\ bbb},   
%       ylabel = {aaa\\ bbb},   
        ]
    \addplot[
        color = blue,
        mark = *,
        line width = 1pt,
        ] coordinates {
        (-30,-10)
        (-20,-10)       
        (-10,0)
        (0,0)
        (10,0)
        (20,10)
        (30,10)
    };  
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
%       ylabel style = {align = left},
%       xlabel style = {align = right},
%       xlabel = {aaa\\ bbb},   
%       ylabel = {aaa\\ bbb},   
        axis lines = center,
        xmin = -80,
        xmax = 60,
        ymin = -15,
        ymax = 15,
        enlarge x limits = 0.05,
        enlarge y limits = 0.05,
        ylabel style = {align = left},
        xlabel style = {align = right},
        xlabel = {aaa\\ bbb},   
        ylabel = {aaa\\ bbb},           
        ]
    \addplot[
        color = blue,
        mark = *,
        line width = 1pt,
        ] coordinates {
        (-30,-10)
        (-20,-10)       
        (-10,0)
        (0,0)
        (10,0)
        (20,10)
        (30,10)
    };  
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think this is a `pgfplots` bug and have reported https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgfplots/issues/404.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Thanks a lot!

Comment: Redefining the related keys to use `/.append style` is surely a workaround, but considering there's so many keys to patch ... Maybe you have to stick to specific order for now.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Yes, I was lucky that I was able to find a workaround by playing with the order :).

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ If you provide an answer (--> mentioning the bug report) then I will accept.

Comment: There is also the smile in the figure. ahahah :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano Thanks for the nice comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem came from the order of keys `[xy]label style` and `axis lines`.

Each of theses keys will modify corresponding `every axis [xyz] label` style, but unlike `[xyz]label style` keys which *append* (`/.append style`) the style, `axis lines` and `axis [xyz] line` keys directly *set* (`/.style`) the style hence make the accumulated style value lost.

I think this is a `pgfplots` bug/flaw, unless the behavior is explicitly documented. And I've reported it https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgfplots/issues/404 (yes, an issue numbered 404, not a 404 page).